# Handling all uncaught errors on Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm building an elixir/phoenix project and want to do some additional handling for all uncaught errors including controller, view, router and socket communication errors.

What I want to do is that catch all uncaught errors and send error information to the external error log aggregator and re-raise the error again to go through original error process.

What would be the best option for me for example with following options? :

- use Plug.ErrorHandler
- use a Custom Plug
- implement a Instrumenter

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Vote to close--very broad question that's asking for opinions.  Maybe you could narrow the question a bit.

Comment: You could check Sentry library for Elixir for some examples how others did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is very opinion-based, but I’d try to do my best to provide the least biased answer.

Phoenix itself [uses a custom module](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/4b0718cc96805c4c87e83bfe7d6faa052565fcaa/lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex#L573), namely [`Plug.Debugger`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Debugger.html#content) for *almost* that purpose in `dev` environment. Most of it’s functionality is providing the feedback, and it seems all you need from there is a custom [`call/2`](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.5.0/lib/plug/debugger.ex#L100-L107) wrapper.

The aforementioned functionality is exactly what [is provided](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.5.0/lib/plug/error_handler.ex#L1) by [`Plug.ErrorHandler`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.ErrorHandler.html#content) so I honestly do not see any reason to reinvent a wheel.